# Finitely generated modules, Jacobson radical

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, homological-algebra, finitely-generated

I'm trying to solve a problem without the assumption of Nakayama's lemma, and this statement clearly implies the Nakayama's lemma.

The statement goes as follow: let $R$ be a ring, and let $M$ be an $R$-module with a finite generating set $T$. Let $T'$ be a subset of T. If there is an ideal $I \subset R$ contained in the Jacobson radical of $R$ such that $T' \subseteq IM$, show that $T \backslash T'$ generates M.

Can someone help me solving this problem please?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can’t solve this problem.

Comment: @kkkkk That's not a question, that's a state of being.  I think the idea is to "get off your behind" so to speak, and a question that is a step toward solving the problem.

Comment: I wish this guy changes his/her ID to something else.

Comment: @kkkkk: As you can see, your question has been closed (by the powers that be) for lack of sufficient context (and it will eventually be deleted). But from your mention of Nakayama's lemma, it's clear that you did at least _some_ work on the problem before posting your question. If you had included some of that work as part of your posted question, the question would probably not have been closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:$\;$If $y\in I$ then $1-y$ is not in any maximal ideal of $R$, hence $1-y$ is a unit  of $R$.

Let $T=\{t_1,...,t_k\}$ and suppose $t_k\in T'$.

Let $N$ be the $R$-submodule of $M$ generated by $\{t_1,...,t_{k-1}\}$.

**Claim:**$\;N=M$.

**Proof:**

It suffice to show $t_k\in N$.

If $t_k=0$, the claim is trivially true, so assume $t_k\ne 0$.

First suppose $k=1$ (i.e., $T=T'=\{t_1\}$).

Then from $t_1\in IM$, we get $t_1=xt_1$ for some $x\in I$, hence $(1-x)t_1=0$.

But then since $1-x$ is a unit of $R$, we get $t_1=0$, contradiction.

Thus the claim holds for the case $k=1$.

Next suppose $k > 1$.

By hypothesis we have $t_k=xm$ for some $x,m$ where $x\in I$ and $m\in M$.

Since $T$ generates $M$, we can write
$$
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
m=r_1t_1+\cdots+r_kt_k
$$
for some $r_1,...,r_k\in R$, hence
\begin{align*}
&
t_k=xm\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
t_k=x(r_1t_1+\cdots+r_kt_k)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
t_k\equiv (xr_k)t_k\;(\text{mod}\;N)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(1-xr_k)t_k\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;N)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
t_k\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;N)\qquad\text{[since $1-xr_k$ is a unit of $R$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
t_k\in N\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which completes the proof of the claim.

Thus $\{t_1,...,t_{k-1}\}$ generates $M$.

Iterating the process, eliminating the elements of $T'$ one at a time, it follows that $T{\,\setminus\,}T'$ generates $M$, as was to be shown.